# ON AWS Elastic beanstalk every-time when we start deploying , deployment get stuck

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk

we have spring boot application running on AWS Elastic beanstalk but every time when we start deploying, deployment gets stuck.
but if we terminate the backend ec2 instances and start new instances then the deployment will go smoothly.
What might be the reason? can someone suggest me the fix?

the error events are below.

> Command failed on instance. Return code: 1 Output: + initctl status eb-ecs + grep -q 'eb-ecs start/' + initctl stop eb-ecs EB_EVENT_FILE=/tmp/eventsfile20221019-657-uyhfrc initctl: Job failed while stopping. Hook /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/enact/00stop-task.sh failed

Comment: Did you check EB log files? EB produces a lot of log files with detailed info on what's happening.

Comment: @Marcin , yes , i found below from EB events : Command failed on instance. Return code: 1 Output: + initctl status eb-ecs + grep -q 'eb-ecs start/' + initctl stop eb-ecs EB_EVENT_FILE=/tmp/eventsfile20221019-657-uyhfrc initctl: Job failed while stopping. Hook /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/enact/00stop-task.sh failed.

but unfortunately the instances were terminated before troubleshooting .